# Converting a flat HTML heading structure to an object graph

Tags: c#, .net, tree, linq-to-xml, openxml

I have a requirement to be able to take a WordML document and convert it to an object graph via it's headings, which will translate to a navigable structure through a web application. This could be analogous to the "Navigation" pane in MS Word.

Here's a bare example of the object structure that I need to get the Word doc into:

```
public class Folder
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Folder ParentFolder { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Folder> Subfolders { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }
}
public class Page
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Folder ContainingFolder { get; set; }
}
```

Hopefully that's self-explanatory. It's basically like a rudimentary file system.

The Word doc can have several sections with any number of nested headings. If we think of a heading structure as a tree, I need each leaf (a heading section with no sub-headings) to be a Page, and every branch to be a Folder. For example:

---

## Heading 1 (a)

Some content (1)

### Heading 2 (b)

#### Heading 3 (c)

Some content (2)

### Heading 2 (d)

#### Heading 3 (e)

Some content (3)

#### Heading 3 (f)

Some content (4)

Heading 4 (g)

Some content (5)

---

In this example, (a) would become the Name of a new Folder with (1) being the Description, and have Subfolders (b) and (d), each of which will have null Descriptions. Since (c) has no sub-headings, it becomes a Page whose Title is (c), Content is (2), and ContainingFolder is (b). Same with (e) and (3). (f) should become a new Folder under ParentFolder (d), with Description of (4), and a new Page for (g), whose Title is (g) and Content is (5).

I hope I haven't lost you yet.

So far, I've tried opening a document with the OpenXML SDK, but since the resulting XML is kind of a pain to work with, I decided to use a library to convert the document into HTML. That gives a nice, clean document that I can using LINQ-to-XML to traverse.

Now I have a flat HTML document with p, h1, h2, etc., tags, but obviously, they aren't nested; they're all siblings. How can I traverse this document and convert each header section into the object graph I explained above?

Some things to note: the document might not always start with H1, and sub-headings might not always be the next immediate sub-heading (e.g., H2 followed by H4). If the highest-level heading is in the middle of the document, we can ignore anything that came before it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it figured out. I haven't tested all cases, like I mentioned in the caveats at the end of the question, but for now, it will work. In case any one stumbles on this and is interested, here's what I did.

First of all, I did end up converting the Word doc to HTML, and then parsing it from there using LINQ to XML. This method is first called by passing in the first header-tagged element in the HTML ('H1', 'H2', etc.), and a Folder object which will contain the output of the Word to Folder/Page structure I described in the question.

```
private Folder ConvertHtmlHeadersToFolderStructure(XElement header, Folder containingFolder)
    {
        // Extract the usable data from the element
        // header.Value
        string title;
        // header.NextNode.ToString() for everything between this and the next header element 
        StringBuilder contentSb; 
        ExtractInfo(header, out title, out contentSb);
        // Determine if this header element is going to be a page or a folder
        // It's a page if the current header element number is greater than or equal to
        // the next header element number, e.g. h3 >= h2; h3 is a page
        XElement nextHeader;
        if (IsElementALeaf(header, out nextHeader))
        {
            containingFolder.Pages.Add(new Page
            {
                Content = contentSb.ToString(),
                Title = title,
                Folder = containingFolder
            });
            if (nextHeader != null)
            {
                int thisHeaderLevel = GetHeaderLevel(header);
                int nextHeaderLevel = GetHeaderLevel(nextHeader);
                Folder upLevelFolder = containingFolder;
                for (int i = 0; i < thisHeaderLevel - nextHeaderLevel; i++)
                {
                    upLevelFolder = upLevelFolder.ParentFolder;
                }
                ConvertHtmlHeadersToFolderStructure(nextHeader, upLevelFolder);
            }
            return containingFolder;
        }
        else
        {
            Folder subFolder = new Folder
            {
                Description = contentSb.ToString(),
                Name = title,
                ParentFolder = containingFolder
            };

            // nextHeader shouldn't be null if we got here
            subFolder = ConvertHtmlHeadersToFolderStructure(nextHeader, subFolder);

            containingFolder.Subfolders.Add(subFolder);

            return containingFolder;
        }
    }
```